# Can't boot into Elementary OS on Macbook without efi boot

Tags: boot, uefi, macbook

Big linux noob ahead, so please be kind if I don't exactly understand everything I'm talking about here.

I installed Ubuntu on my father's old macbook 4.1 a few days ago, and it worked just fine. Today we tried to install Elementary OS (multiple times) but it always got stuck on a black screen with a blinking white line - holding shift during boot did nothing.

After searching around a bit, I decided to try and reinstall grub2 with the tool "[boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)". Didn't fix the issue, so I tried to reboot to reinstall Elementary without installing updates. I noticed that there now was a third option in the apple boot-menu: "EFI boot" (aside from "Windows", the one that would normally start ubuntu, and then my usb installation media). I thought "what the hell" and tried the option.

Here I am greeted by a quick screen that says

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi: Not Found
```

From here I can simply choose "elementary os" and the computer boots as it is supposed to.

I also tried some other things in the midst of things, including following [this guide for Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall), and applying it to ubuntu.

Sorry if this has already been answered

Comment: Did you check this link: https://github.com/aroman/freya-on-a-mac ?

Comment: Are you using 0.3.1 or 0.3.2

Comment: I managed to fix the issue myself after reinstalling using this guide http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by reinstalling (though I don't think it was necessary) following [these](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/) instructions, though I think it was mainly the last part that helped.